# Vim digraphs (How to express variable powers in Vim?)

Tags: vim

I'm not able to type a^m in vim, however a^n is possible with Ctrl+k anS.
Am I doing something wrong? i.e. can I get this done using some other syntax or maybe I need a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [`:help digraph-table`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/digraph.txt.html#digraph-table), you'll only find the digraph for powers of `n`:

> ```
> ⁿ nS  207F    8319    SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER N `
> ```

Looking at [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts), the reason seems to be that there's only a Unicode codepoint for superscript `n`, but not `m` (or any other Latin letter).